# Does this proof show that a one-to-one mapping of a natural number segment into itself exists?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, pigeonhole-principle

This is from **Fundamentals of Mathematics, Volume I: Foundations of Mathematics: The Real Number System and Algebra**, by Behnke, Heinrich, et al.

A mapping $f$ is defined to be one-to-one if it has the property $f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right)\implies x=y.$  A segment $A_n$ is the set of natural numbers less than or equal to $n.$  The expression $n^\prime$ denotes the successor of $n.$

> *A one-to-one mapping $f$ of $A_{n}$ into itself [i.e., $f\left(A_{n}\right)\subseteq A_{n}$]
> is a mapping onto $A_{n}.$*

> We prove this theorem by the argument from $n$ to $n^{\prime}$.
> For $n=1$ the assertion is clear, since $1$ is the only element
> of $A_{1}.$ Now let $f$ be a one-to-one mapping of $A_{n^{\prime}}$
> into itself. If $n^{\prime}\ne f\left(x\right)$ for all $x\le n,$
> then $f$ induces to a one-to-one mapping of $A_{n}$ into itself,
> so that by the induction hypothesis $f\left(A_{n}\right)=A_{n}.$
> But then we can only have $f\left(n^{\prime}\right)=n^{\prime}$,
> and consequently $f\left(A_{n^{\prime}}\right)=A_{n^{\prime}}.$ But
> if $n^{\prime}=f\left(k\right)$ for a number $k\le n$, then by setting

> $$
> g\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
> f\left(x\right) & \text{for }k\ne x\le n\\
> f\left(n^{\prime}\right) & \text{for }k=x
> \end{cases},
> $$

> we define a mapping $g$ of $A_{n}$ into itself, since $f\left(n^{\prime}\right)\ne n^{\prime}=f\left(k\right)$
> follows from $n^{\prime}\ne k$. The one-to-one character of $g$ follows
> easily from that of $f,$ so that by the induction hypothesis we have
> $g\left(A_{n}\right)=A_{n},$ and consequently $f\left(A_{n}\right)=A_{n}.$

The induction hypothesis of the proof assumes the existence of a one-to-one mapping of a segment into itself.  **Is it still necessary to prove that such a one-to-one self-mapping exists?**

The book later proves that an onto self mapping of a segment is one-to-one.  Thus saying that a self-mapping of a segment is one-to-one is equivalent to saying that it is onto. But, again we assume the existence of an onto self-mapping.

Are we actually assuming the existence of one-to-one self-mappings of segments *a priori* and continuing on our merry way without ever encountering a contradiction?

Comment: This existence is obvious but needed nowhere in the proof.

Comment: @AnneBauval Treating a mathematical fact as "obvious" in foundational mathematics seems inappropriate.

Comment: I fully disagree. It helps to focus on less obvious facts, like your apparent misunderstanding of the induction principle. As for the obviousness mentionned here, see the sentence beginning with "Of course" in Ethan's answer. That answer details my initial comment.

Comment: What I get out of the proof(s) is that we don't need to determine the existence of the mappings in order for the proofs to work.  I doesn't seem hard to prove that such mappings other than the identity mapping exist.  They are simply permutations which can be generated algorithmically.  That is, if we accept that the identity mapping is one-to-one and onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This argument just shows that such a one to one mapping (should any exist) must also be onto.

(Of course there are many such mappings: $n!$ of them for $A_n$. But you don't need to know that for this argument to be correct.)

Comment: I think I stated my question poorly.  Perhaps I should post basically the same material but ask if we ever prove the existence of these mappings.  But that will have to wait.  Your answer to the question I asked seems correct.

Comment: There's clearly always $1$, the identity. Proving there are $n!$ isn't hard.